# JMeter - JSR223 PreProcessor is getting failed in the GitHub for OTP creation

Tags: performance, github, jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to execute a .jmx script in the GitHub. The login page requires a OTP, which I am generating using org.jboss.aerogear. However, it seems when I am executing the script in GitHub the script is not generating this OTP and throwing 406 (Not Acceptable). Can anyone please guide me on this issue please.
This is running perfectly in JMeter but getting error in GitHub.

Do I need to add this specific driver and how?

[image: Jmeter Preprocessor]

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you face any "error" first of all take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), normally it contains the reason or at least a clue so you can figure out or guess the error cause. If it doesn't - [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the test elements you're using.

Most probably you need to add the .jar file which provides this Totp class (along with [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), if any) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) to JMeter installation in "Github" (whatever it means) and the error will go away